# matlab : out of memory with convenable confi of pc

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

I block on my problem that I will wrote in details below. During 3 days I tried a lot of differents things, none worked..

If anyone have an idea of what to do !

Here is my message error :

```
the call to "ft_selectdata" took 0 seconds
preprocessing
Out of memory. Type "help memory" for your options.

Error in ft_preproc_dftfilter (line 187)
  tmp  = exp(2*1i*pi*freqs(:)*time); % complex sin and cos

Error in ft_preproc_dftfilter (line 144)
    filt = ft_preproc_dftfilter(filt, Fs, Fl(i), 'dftreplace', dftreplace, 'dftbandwidth',
    dftbandwidth(i), 'dftneighbourwidth', dftneighbourwidth(i)); % enumerate all options

Error in preproc (line 464)
  dat     = ft_preproc_dftfilter(dat, fsample, cfg.dftfreq, optarg{:});

Error in ft_preprocessing (line 375)
    [dataout.trial{i}, dataout.label, dataout.time{i}, cfg] = preproc(data.trial{i}, data.label,
    data.time{i}, cfg, begpadding, endpadding);

Error in EEG_Prosocial_script (line 101)
    data_intpl = ft_preprocessing(cfg, allData_preprosses);
 
187   tmp  = exp(2*1i*pi*freqs(:)*time); % complex sin and cos
```

There is some informations from matlab about my computer and about the caracteristics of the calcul

```
Maximum possible array: 7406 MB (7.766e+09 bytes)* 
Memory available for all arrays: 7406 MB (7.766e+09 bytes) * 
Memory used by MATLAB: 4195 MB (4.398e+09 bytes) 
Physical Memory (RAM): 12206 MB (1.280e+10 bytes)
Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available. 

K>> whos Name                      
               Size       Bytes         Class    Attributes
freqs         7753x1      62024         double 
li            1x1          16           double   complex 
time          1x1984512  15876096       double
```

**So there the config of the computer which failed to run the script (Alienware aurora R4) :**

Ram : 4gb free / 12 @ 1,6Ghz --> 2x (4Gb 1600Mhz) - 2x (2Gb 1600 MHz)

Intel core i7-3820 4 core 8 threads 3,7 GHz 1 CPU

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 690 2gb

RAM : Kingston KVT8FP HYC

Hard disk : SSD kingston 250Go SATA 3"

**This code work on this computer (Dell inspiron 14-500) : config**

Ram 4 Go of memory DDR4 2 666 MHz (4 Go x 1)

Intel® Core™ i5-8265U 8e generatio, (6 Mo memory, 3,9 GHz)

Intel® UHD Graphics 620

Hard disk SATA 2,5" 500 Go 5 400 tr/min

Thank you

Kind regards,

Comment: I can’t tell what you are trying to accomplish. Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly. If the code works on one computer and doesn’t on another with similar amount of memory, you are likely not inputting the same data in the two cases.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will add the full code until the error later.

Answer (score 0):

by doing `freqs(:)*time` you are trying to create a 7753*1984512 size array, and you dont have memory for that... (you will need ~123 gigabytes for that, or 1.2309e+11 bytes, where your computer has ~7e+09)

see for example the case for :

```
f=rand(7,1);
t=rand(1,19);
size(f(:)*t)

ans =

 7    19
```

what you want do to is probably a for loop per time element etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it is the fieldtrip tool which use this command. In my case I just try to use fieldtrip to process electroencephalography data into numeric. And this same script work on a other computer it's why I'm a bit confused . Thank you for you answer